# Spring Integration 5.2.3- Deadlock issue with int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter

Tags: java, jdbc, spring-integration, deadlock

I am getting following exception

*java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)\nCaused by: org.springframework.dao.ConcurrencyFailureException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [SELECT request.id, request.provision_action FROM tenant t, tenant_provision_request request where t.id = request.tenant_id and t.provision_status in ('pending', 'success') and request.provisioning_status='pending' for update]; ERROR: deadlock detected\n  Detail: Process 28666 waits for ShareLock on transaction 75033096; blocked by process 22536.\nProcess 22536 waits for ShareLock on transaction 75033739; blocked by process 28666.\n  Hint: See server log for query details.\n  Where: while rechecking updated tuple (2299,92) in relation "tenant_provision_request"; nested exception is com.edb.util.PSQLException: ERROR: deadlock detected\n  Detail: Process 28666 waits for ShareLock on transaction 75033096; blocked by process 22536.\nProcess 22536 waits for ShareLock on transaction 75033739; blocked by process 28666.\n  Hint: See server log for query details.\n  Where: while rechecking updated tuple (2299,92) in relation "tenant_provision_request"\n\tat org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:113)\n\tat org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)\n\tat org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)\n\tat org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)\n\tat org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1443)\n\tat org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:633)\n\tat org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:669)\n\tat org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:694)\n\tat org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:748)\n\tat org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:216)\n\tat*

I have a 2 nodes tomcat server and following is my query.Database here is ppas

```
  <int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter
          id="provisionAdapter"
          channel="dataChannel" 
          data-source="dataSource" 
          query="${query.pending.provisioning}"
          update="${update.pending.provisioning}" 
          max-rows-per-poll="10">
   </int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

In property file we have:

```
   `query.pending.provisioning=SELECT request.id, request.provision_action FROM tenant t, 
     tenant_provision_request request where t.id = request.tenant_id and t.provision_status in 
     ('pending', 'success') and request.provisioning_status='pending' for update


   update.pending.provisioning=update tenant_provision_request tpr set tpr.provisioning_status 
   ='in_progress' where tpr.id in (:id); update tenant t set t.provision_status = 
   'in_progress' from tenant_provision_request tpr where tpr.id in (:id) and t.id = 
    tpr.tenant_id; `
```

Comment: Can you edit your question, please, some way that stack trace is readable? Why those new line delimiters are present in the text?

Comment: > See server log for query details.

Probably sounds more like not Spring Integration related issue. You need to consult with your DBA what might be wrong with your queries.